# Binomial Theorem Proofs

Tags: combinatorics

I would love to get some help on these binomial theorem proofs: I'm sorry I do not know how to format the question to make it look nicer.

1. $$\sum_{r=0}^n {n \choose r}(r+1)(2)^r=3^{n-1}(2n+3)$$
2. $$\sum_{a1+a2+a3+a4=n}{n \choose a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4}{a_1}{a_2}{3}^{a_3}=n(n-1)6^{n-2}$$

n is fixed in #2

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: How is $\binom{n}{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4}$ defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Consider
   $$\begin{aligned}\left.\frac{d}{dx}(1+x)^n\right|_{x=2} &=n \times 1 \times (1+2)^{n-1} \\ 
   &= \left.\frac{d}{dx} \left( \sum_{r=0}^n \genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{0}{n}{r} 1^{n-1} x^{r}\right)\right|_{x=2} = \sum_{r=0}^n \genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{0}{n}{r} r \ 2^{r-1} \end{aligned} \tag{1}\label{1}$$
   Multiplying everything by 2 and then adding $3^n$ yields
   $$ 2\left(\sum_{r=0}^n \genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{0}{n}{r} r \ 2^{r-1}  \right) + 3^n = \sum_{r=0}^n \genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{0}{n}{r} r \ 2^{r} + (1+2)^n = \sum_{r=0}^n \genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{0}{n}{r} (r+1) \ 2^{r} \tag{2}\label{2}$$
   Doing the same to $n (1+2)^{n-1}$ does yield the r.h.s. of 1.
2. Consider
   $$ \begin{aligned} \left.\frac{d}{dx} \frac{d}{dy} (x+y+3+1)^n \right|_{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{1}{x=1}{y=1}} & = \left. \frac{d}{dx} \frac{d}{dy}  \left( \sum_{a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4=n} x^{a_1} y^{a_2} 3^{a_3} 1^{a_4}\right) \right|_{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{1}{x=1}{y=1}}\\
   &= \sum_{a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4=n} a_1\, a_2\, 3^{a_3}
   \end{aligned} \tag{3}\label{3}$$
   but at the same time, one has
   $$ \begin{aligned} \left.\frac{d}{dx} \frac{d}{dy} (x+y+3+1)^n \right|_{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{1}{x=1}{y=1}} &= \left.\frac{d}{dx} n\, (x+1+3+1)^{n-1} \right|_{x=1} \\
   &= n\, (n-1)\, (1+1+3+1)^{n-2} = n\, (n-1)\, 6^{n-2} 
   \end{aligned} \tag{4}\label{4}$$

*Remark:* Multinomial formula
$$ \left( x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_d \right)^n = \sum_{\left\lvert\boldsymbol{\alpha}\right\rvert =n} \genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{0}{\left\lvert\boldsymbol{\alpha}\right\rvert}{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}\, \mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{\alpha}} \tag{5}\label{5}
 $$
where $\boldsymbol{\alpha}=\big(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots ,\alpha_d \big)\in \mathbb{N}^d$ is a multi-index, and $\left\lvert\boldsymbol{\alpha}\right\rvert = \alpha_1 +\alpha_2 +\cdots +\alpha_d $ its length. $x^{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}$ means $x_1^{\alpha_1}\times x_2^{\alpha_2} \times \cdots \times x_d^{\alpha_d}$ and
\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
 \genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{0}{\left\lvert\boldsymbol{\alpha}\right\rvert}{\boldsymbol{\alpha}} & = \genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{0}{n}{\alpha_1} \genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{0}{n-\alpha_1}{\alpha_2}\, \cdots \, \genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{0}{n-\alpha_1 -\alpha_2 - \cdots - \alpha_{d-1}}{\alpha_d}= \frac{n!}{\alpha_1 !\, (n-\alpha_1)!} \frac{(n-\alpha_1)!}{\alpha_2 !\, (n-\alpha_1-\alpha_2)!}\, \cdots\, \frac{(n-\alpha_1 -\alpha_2 - \cdots - \alpha_{d-1})!}{\alpha_d !\, 0 !} \\
 & = \frac{n!}{\alpha_1 !\, \alpha_2 ! \, \cdots \, \alpha_d!}
 \end{split} \tag{6}\label{6}
 \end{equation}
For a given $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ this coefficient is the number of times the factor $x^{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}$ appears in the development of $\left(x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_d \right)^n$. For example $\genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{0}{n}{r}= \frac{n!}{r!\, (n-1)!} $ could be written $\genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{0}{n}{r,n-r}$ with the notation of #2.

Comment: How are you able to simply multiply everything by 2 and add 3^n? Like what allows you to do that? I also do not really understand your reasoning for #2

Comment: If $A=B$ then $2 A + 3^n = 2 B + 3^n$

Comment: Why did you substitute a1 a2 and a4 for x,y, and 1 and what brought you to that

Comment: I guess you are talking about equation (3). It is the same trick as in (1), we are taking the derivative of some function then evaluate it at a specific point. We reckonize that $a_1 = \left. \frac{d}{dx} x^{a_1}\right|_{x=1}$ (and similarly for $y$, regardless of if the equality is multiplied by a constant). There is a part of guessing, the main idea I had was to make a link to the binomial or the multinomial formula (+ I knew about the above mentionned trick)

Answer (score 2):

This might be useful,

> $$(x+1)^n=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}x^r\\\frac{d}{dx}\left[x(1+x)^r\right]=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}(r+1)x^r$$

Answer (score 1):

It is often possible to show such identities by solving the same combinatorial problem twice. This is also called [double counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(proof_technique)).

For the first problem, consider $n$ persons, each person either wears a red, blue or green t-shirt. Furthermore *at  most one* of the persons wearing a read or blue t-shirt may also wear a funny hat. How many ways can we distribute the t-shirts and the optional funny hat?

1. *Solution 1:* If no one wears a funny hat there are $3^n$ ways to distribute the t-shirt colours over the $n$ persons. If someone wears the funny hat, we have $n$ persons to choose from, this person can only wear red or blue ($2$ options) the remaining $n-1$ persons, can wear all 3 shirt colours. We end up with $n \times 2 \times 3^{n-1}$ possibilities. In total that makes $3^n + 2n3^{n-1} = 3^{n-1}(2n + 3)$.
2. *Solution 2*: Let us count the number of ways to distribute the t-shirts and the funny hat, if exactly $r$ persons wear either a red or blue t-shirt: First we must choose which $r$ persons wears a red or blue t-shirt this can be done in $n \choose r$ ways. Then for each of the $r$ persons we choose if they wear red or blue, this makes for $2^r$ ways. Finally, choose which person should wear the funny hat or if no one should, this makes for $r+1$ possibilities. In total this gives us ${n \choose r} (r+1) 2^r$. We then sum over all the possible number of persons wearing red or blue t-shirts: $\sum_{r=0}^n {n \choose r} (r+1) 2^r$.

Since, we counted the same thing twice the two must be equal. I encourage you to try solving the second identity using a similar argument.